# Where to store macros for TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

I'm switching from Winedt to TeXstudio. I have lots of Winedt macros and I would like to write new ones for TeXstudio.
Now I read about available macro functions, but I still don't understand where I should store the macro file?
If I add macro to that form **Macros->Edit** Macros, it appears in `.INI` file (one line like `Macros\0=test`).
But its hard to edit such a macros.

Question, is it possible/simple to load javascript macros from files?

It would be great to have a **Macros** directory, where you could store all your macros.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  A hint: to indicate macro code in your posting use backticks around the code.

Answer (score 3):

There is no official way to import macros. All creation and editing should be done via the dialog. As a workaround for importing many macros, you could write a script, that adds the corresponding entries to the `.ini`.

The format is `Macros\<number>=<name>, <tag>, <abbreviation>, <trigger>`.

The `<number>` should be consecutive. Each of `<name>, <tag>, <abbreviation>, <trigger>` are strings (only require quotes if they contain a colon themselves).

However, we don't guarantee that the format will not change in later versions.

*Note*: I don't know the macros of Winedt, but macros used there won't work in TXS because TXS has its own API for the editor.

Comment: Winedit macros are very painful to program. But in other hand it has a good possibilities to manage (run, store,..) them.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to create macros as a separate files. Than with macro manager
assign them to some named object? Than would be good to run them on a shortcut or add it to mouse menu or to create separate window menu. Lets say, store just a full path of macro file in .INI: 1. Test_macro1 = "c:/texstudio/macros/...../testmacro.something" 2. Test_macro2 = "c:/texstudio/macros/...../testmacro2.something" 3. Test_macro3 = "c:/texstudio/macros/...../testmacro3.something"